# No active configuration. Make sure GIDClientID is set in Info.plist

Tags: xcode, google-signin

I am very new to app development. I was trying to configure my GoogleSignInButton Callback function.

I get the error:

> No active configuration.  Make sure GIDClientID is set in Info.plist.

However, my Info.plist defines GIDClientID along with the value generated as advised [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating)

[image]

OS: Version 13.0 Beta

Xcode: Version 14.1 beta 3

Answer (score 15):

In order to resolve this issues, you don't need to add anything into the info.plist. you need to setup `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.configuration = config`

https://github.com/WesCSK/SwiftUI-Firebase-Authenticate-Using-Google-Sign-In/blob/starting/README.md#updated-steps-for-v700-of-google-signin

```
guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else { return }
        
// Create Google Sign In configuration object.
let config = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientID)
        
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.configuration = config

....
```

Answer (score 3):

Google documentation at Firebase Login methods is worse than....
So, if you are using 8.6.0 you can use GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(withPresenting: presentingVC), but add ClientID in Info.plist like here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHCiQ.png)

Regarding the main issue, from your picture I see that you put the URLSchema at GIDClientID, they are a little bit different.
Eg. GIDclientID: xxxx-xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
URLSchema: com.googleusercontent.apps.xxxx-xxxxxx.

Try like that.

I get my clientId using this line of debug in my code
guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID

Comment: remove the "Answer for Anna"  the answer should address the problem. if you need write it as a comment

Answer (score 2):

Don't add new property named "GIDClientID" into the Info.plist of target project, use CLIENT_ID which is defined in GoogleService-Info.plist instead.

Find more details here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74897652/19683708

Answer (score 0):

Same error. I'm newbie too, it helped for me to reinstall packages (GoogleSignIn and FirebaseAuth) with older versions (6.0.0 and 8.6.0) so `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: config, presenting: self)` is available. This is a temporary solution till we find working way.

Answer (score -1):

This changes in google sign is new. Also `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: config, presenting: self)` is not available anymore. `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(withPresenting: presentingVC)` replaced it. But I got same error. Hope to someone find an answer

Comment: Google recommends to add it to the info.plist: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating