# Make sure GIDClientID is set in Info.plist new GoogleSignIn IOS version

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-signin

I'm just trying to configure the new **GoogleSignIn** IOS and keep getting the error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'No active configuration.  Make sure GIDClientID is set in Info.plist.'
```

I've scoured the web and the one or two questions on here for solutions however I can't seem to get this error to clear no matter what. This is in my URL Schemes:

[image: URL Schemes]

and this is my Info.plist

[image: info.plist]

Does anyone have any examples of exactly how my `info.plist` should look?

Cheers.

Comment: Don't alter your plist at this point. If this is a clean project i.e. you've not already made changes, following this guide [Auth Using Google sign-on](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin) works. A guess is you missed a step along the way which may be the code required to make it work. It's a good idea to provide details in questions so we understand the issue and can eliminate variables. For example, you may have omitted step 2) - *In your app delegate's application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method, configure the FirebaseApp object.* `FirebaseApp.configure()`

Answer (score 4):

I've just faced a similar issue when implementing Firebase Authentication w/ GoogleSignIn.

If you think that you will add new property "GIDClientID" into Info.plist of target project, DON'T DO THAT.

Below are the guidelines of Firebase for Authentication w/ Google, this code fixes the issue above but the way it shows how to use signIn method is invalid at this moment:

```
guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else { return }

// Create Google Sign In configuration object.
let config = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientID)

// Start the sign in flow!
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: config, presenting: self) { [unowned self] user, error in
  // ...
}
```

There's a solution is to set the configuration to GIDSignIn.sharedInstance before calling signIn method, as below:

```
guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else { return }

// Create Google Sign In configuration object.
let config = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientID)

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.configuration = config

let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
let windowScenes = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene
let window = windowScenes?.windows.first
guard let rootViewController = window?.rootViewController else { return }

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(withPresenting: rootViewController) { signInResult, error in
    // ...
}
```

Comment: you should add your code in question not just an image of it read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Parisa.H.R Thanks for your comment. The image I attached is sample code of Firebase, and I already shared full code of the my solution so I'm not sure what is missing here. Could you tell me in details about the missing thing so that I could make a complete answer?

Comment: yeah, I say it because search engines can't recognize it like this, you answer perfectly but add codes instead of images and use images to show outputs. I see the GitHub link but if you add only a link your answer will be linked only and others flags it. I see it in the review part because other users flag it.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R thanks for your detailed guidelines. I've just reformat the answer, remove image of code, link of gist.github.com and use code instead. Is it ok now? :)

Comment: its perfect now :)